# Install ROS Ubuntu 20.04.6

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, ros

I am attempting to install ROS on Ubuntu 20.04.6 following this guide https://linuxopsys.com/topics/install-ros-noetic-on-ubuntu
First two steps work okay.

But when I get to try:
*sudo apt update*

Then I receive this error:
*The repository 'https://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.*

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The packages.ros.org server currently has a certificate error. Apt is likely receiving that error, which is why it cannot find the Release file (which does indeed exist in the expected location). Please let the ROS folks know about their server problem. Does not seem an Ubuntu-related issue.